# Bitbucket CI/CD Pipeline with aws elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, bitbucket, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, bitbucket-pipelines

I am trying to implement Bitbucket CI/CD pipeline to deploy .net core application on AWS elastic beanstalk. The .net core application getting successfully published, but when I am trying to deploy on AWS elastic beanstalk it is giving following error.

> ✖ Deployment failed. Environment "{my-application-environment}" is
>   running a different version "{version-number}".

Also on AWS elastic beanstalk I am getting the following error,

> During an aborted deployment, some instances may have deployed the new
>   application version. To ensure all instances are running the same
>   version, re-deploy the appropriate application version.

Below is my bitbucket-pipelines.yml file

```
image: microsoft/dotnet:3.0-sdk 

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
       script:
          - echo "Hello Bitbucket !"

    - step: 
        name: build publish prepare and zip 
        caches: 
          - dotnetcore 
        script:
          - apt-get update && apt-get install --yes zip 
          - export PROJECT_NAME=$PROJECT_NAME
          - dotnet restore $PROJECT_NAME
          - dotnet build $PROJECT_NAME 
          - dotnet publish $PROJECT_NAME --self-contained --runtime win-x64 --configuration Debug
          - zip -j site.zip /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/{my-project-name}/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.0/win-x64/publish/*  -x aws-windows-deployment-manifest.json
          - zip -r -j application.zip site.zip /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/{my-project-name}/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.0/win-x64/publish/aws-windows-deployment-manifest.json 

        artifacts:
          - application.zip

    - step:
        name: upload to elasticbeanstalk
        script:
          - pipe: atlassian/aws-elasticbeanstalk-deploy:0.5.0
            variables:
              APPLICATION_NAME: $APPLICATION_NAME
              AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
              AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
              AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
              #COMMAND: 'upload-only'
              ZIP_FILE: 'application.zip'
              ENVIRONMENT_NAME: $ENVIRONMENT_NAME
              WAIT: 'true'
              VERSION_LABEL: 'deploy-WebApi-$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER'
```

The variables I have already configured in pipeline settings and pipeline is also enabled.

Is there something wrong with my .yml file?

Any help on this appreciated !